# How to use iteration to assign value to different variables? Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to assign value like following:

```
df01 = 1
df02 = 2
df03 = 3
...
df82 = 82
```

How can I write code to assign value like this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't. Use a list.

Comment: or a dict.......